# How can I add CGPoint objects to an NSArray the easy way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have about 50 CGPoint objects that describe something like a "path", and I want to add them to an NSArray. It's going to be a method that will just return the corresponding CGPoint for an given index. I don't want to create 50 variables like p1 = ...; p2 = ..., and so on. Is there an easy way that would let me to define those points "instantly" when initializing the NSArray with objects?

Answer (score 330, accepted):

With `UIKit` Apple added support for CGPoint to `NSValue`, so you can do:

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.5, 6.6)],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(7.7, 8.8)],
                     nil];
```

List as many [NSValue] instances as you have CGPoint, and end the list in nil. All objects in this structure are auto-released.

On the flip side, when you're pulling the values out of the array:

```
NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];
```

Comment: For scalar types, have a look at NSNumber... you'll see constructors like numberWithBool: numberWithInteger: numberWithFloat:, numberWithUnsignedShort:, etc.

Comment: Alternatively you can use NSValue directly: [NSValue valueWithBytes: &someStructSockaddr objCType: @encode(struct sockaddr)] for instance.

Comment: In my case CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue]; did not work. However CGPoint p = [val pointValue]; did work.

Answer (score 7):

I use this:

Create array:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(30.0, 150.0)],[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(41.67, 145.19)]];
```

Get 1st CGPoint object:

```
CGPoint myPoint = [myArray[0] CGPointValue];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also write this in a minimal form of:

```
CGPoint myArray[] = { CGPointMake(5.5, 6.6), CGPointMake(7.7, 8.8) };

CGPoint p2 = myArray[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at `CFMutableArray`? That might work better for you.