# Is there a way to put a scalar type like CGPoint (or any self created) into a NSArray?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, nsarray

Probably I could create a class that holds an CGPoint as instance variable, like a wrapper. Does that make sense? I feel uncomfortable with that, though. I hope there is an better solution.

How about any self-created scalar type? Like MyCoolScalarType?

Comment: By the way, aren't you repeating yourself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899600/how-can-i-add-cgpoint-objects-to-an-nsarray-the-easy-way

Comment: Yes, he doesn't appear to want people to respond in the comments to his previous questions, but likes asking the same question again with slightly different phrasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it an object. You could try this:

```
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(1.f,1.f);

[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
```

This goes for pretty much every scalar you want to put in an NSArray:

```
CGFloat foo = 1.f;

[NSNumber numberWithFloat:foo];
```

Comment: How about own defined scalar types? like MyCoolScalar?

Comment: From the NSValue documentation (which you should look through): "An NSValue object is a simple container for a single C or Objective-C data item. It can hold any of the scalar types such as int, float, and char, as well as pointers, structures, and object ids."

Comment: Alex beat me to it. :) But he's right. So, basically you're still wrapping. But it's a very good and much practiced method.

Answer (score 1):

[NSValue](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can box a CGPoint value into an NSValue object. It is documented in [NSValue UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).