# How to wrap a Struct into NSObject

Tags: iphone, struct, nsmutablearray, nsvalue

this is supposed to be trivial… I think, but I can't find a way how to wrap a Struct variable into an `NSObject`. Is there a method to do so? If not, how would I go about adding a struct into an `NSMutableArray`?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to put a c-struct in an NSArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516991/whats-the-best-way-to-put-a-c-struct-in-an-nsarray)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Hm, try to look at the `NSValue` at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue

You can use it like

```
struct aStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
typedef struct aStruct aStruct;
```

Then sort of "wrap" it to an `NSValue` object like:

```
aStruct struct; struct.a = 0; struct.b = 0;
NSValue *anObj = [NSValue value:&struct withObjCType:@encode(aStruct)];
NSArray *array = @[anObj];
```

To pull the struct out from `NSValue` use:

```
NSValue *anObj = [array firstObject];
aStruct struct;
[anObj getValue:&struct];
```

I guess later on, you can have a category from NSValue to make that better =D

Answer (score 13):

Something like like this would be the category [@Rpranata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5692276/149008) is talking about :)

```
struct _Pair
{
    short val;
    short count;
};
typedef struct _Pair Pair;

@interface NSValue (Pair)
+ (id)valueWithPair:(Pair)pair;
- (Pair)pairValue;
@end

@implementation NSValue (Pair)
+ (id)valueWithPair:(Pair)pair
{
    return [NSValue value:&pair withObjCType:@encode(Pair)];
}
- (Pair)pairValue
{
    Pair pair; [self getValue:&pair]; return pair;
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
// Boxing
Pair pair; pair.val = 2; pair.count = 1;
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithPair:pair];

// Unboxing
NSValue value = ...
Pair anotherPair = [value pairValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+ (NSValue *)valueWithCGAffineTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform;`

From the docs: "Creates a new value object containing the specified CoreGraphics affine transform structure."

```
CGAffineTransform fooAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
[NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:fooAffineTransform];
```

+valueWithCGAffineTransform has existed since iOS 2.0.