# Optional dynamic properties in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm attempting to compile the following Swift class:

```
class Waypoint: NSObject {
    dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
}
```

But I get the following compiler error:

> Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

If I change `coordinate` to be non-optional everything works just fine. I suppose this makes sense, since Objective-C has no concept of optionals. Is there any known solution or workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You probably want an observer on that property ? For what purpose (just to know when the property changed) ? _Maybe I'll be able to suggest you an alternative._

Comment: @lchamp correct, I want an observer for integration with ReactiveCocoa

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Objective-C, you can use `nil` to signal the absence of value, but only on object types. Swift generalizes this (and makes it type-safe) with the `Optional` generic type: you can have an `Optional<NSObject>`, a.k.a. `NSObject?`, but you can also have an `Int?` or a `CLLocationCoordinate2D?`.

But `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a struct — if you use it in Objective-C, you can't assign `nil` to a variable of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. This is why you get this error.

As for an (ugly) workaround, you could wrap `CLLocationCoordinate2D` in a object:

```
class CLLocationCoordinate2DObj: NSObject {
    let val: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    init(_ val: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.val = val
    }
}

class Waypoint: NSObject {
    dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DObj?
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't find a more general solution with a generic object wrapper class for structs, as Objective-C doesn't have generics… An alternative would be to use `NSValue` as object type as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691881/how-to-wrap-a-struct-into-nsobject), but I doubt that it would be more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think I'll create my own `Coordinate` class as you recommend and give it a `toCLLocationCoordinate2D` method unless there's a more elegant way to support typecasting it like: `coordinate as CLLocationCoordinate2D`