# Dynamic optional properties in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, realm, option-type

I have seen this post [Optional dynamic properties in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027741/optional-dynamic-properties-in-swift) but I don't want to have to wrap up the class in an `NSObject`.  This just is concerning the Realm database I don't have to have `nil` properties but it would be a nice way I think to model my database.  In the Realm documentation which can be found here https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ it says optionals are supported.  Here is my

**Code**

```
dynamic var complete: Bool? = nil
```

and here is my

**Error**

```
Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

I know this is the same code and error as the post above but I am just curious if the Realm documentation says it supports it do they have another work around?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the docs on [supported types](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types) and [optional properties](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#optional-properties).

> `String`, `NSDate`, `NSData` and Object properties can be optional. Storing optional numbers is done using [`RealmOptional`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/RealmOptional.html).
>
> `RealmOptional` supports `Int`, `Float`, `Double`, `Bool`, and all of the sized versions of `Int` (`Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`).

So optionals are supported for `String`, `NSDate`, `NSData` and `Object` types nicely with the standard swift syntax.

For other numeric types (such as `Bool`) that is done with `RealmOptional`. Then to use a variable of this `RealmOptional` type you access its `value` property, which is an optional that represents your underlying value.

```
// definition (defined with let)
let complete = RealmOptional<Bool>()  // defaults to nil
// usage
complete.value = false  // set non-nil value
...
complete.value = nil    // set to nil again
```

Comment: you need to change `let complete: RealmOptional<Bool>()` to `let complete = RealmOptional<Bool>()`