# Add and extract struct from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, struct, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way to put a c-struct in an NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516991/whats-the-best-way-to-put-a-c-struct-in-an-nsarray)

I need to create an array of structures, such as:

```
typedef struct
{
    int fill;
    BOOL busy;
} MapCellST;
```

How can I add instances of this structure in NSMutableArray and how I can extract copies of the structure and work with its properties later?

Answer (score 13):

Wrap the struct in an `NSValue`:

```
MapCellSt x;
NSValue* value = [NSValue value:&x withObjCType:@encode(MapCellSt)];
```

To extract it later:

```
[value getValue:&x];
```

Comment: I did this solution but it gives a bad access error

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSMutableDictionary` rather than `NSMutableArray`.

**typedef struct {...} MyStruct;**

```
NSMutableString* myKey = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"MyKey"];
NSValue *myStructPtr = [NSValue value:&myStruct withObjCType:@encode( MyStruct )];
[myMutableDictionary setObject:myStructPtr forKey:myKey];
```

Answer (score -2):

Ya can't.

Only real Obj-C objects can be added directly to NSMutableArray and friends; in order to do what you are describing you would have to create a class with the properties of the struct you are wanting to use.

**Edit:** As Tamás says, you can also use an NSValue; but in all likelihood creating a class for your MapCell is a better idea.