# iOS: Objectifying MKCoordinateSpan to put in an array

Tags: ios, nsarray, mapkit, mkcoordinatespan

Im trying to find a direct way to put MKCoordinateSpan into an array without breaking it down to lat and long and store it in an NSArray. Not sure if there is such way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add and extract struct from NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704722/add-and-extract-struct-from-nsmutablearray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
MKCoordinateSpan currentSpan;
currentSpan = ...; // Set the span to somethinf
NSValue *spanVal = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&currentSpan objCType:@encode(MKCoordinateSpan)];
...
MKCoordinateSpan currentSpanBack;
[spanVal getValue:&currentSpanBack];
```

Comment: I never tried this myself, but I've seen examples that suggest that it might work.

Answer (score 1):

```
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.0, 1.0);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&span length:sizeof(span)];

MKCoordinateSpan back;
[data getBytes:&back length:sizeof(back)];

NSLog(@"%f",back.latitudeDelta);
```

Comment: pretty much the same approach as below I guess? +1 for the effort :)