# Use Struct with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way to put a c-struct in an NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516991/whats-the-best-way-to-put-a-c-struct-in-an-nsarray)

How can I use struct inside NSMutableArray?

Comment: You can create an NSObject subclass that is, in essence, a struct, and use that subclass.

Comment: I don't want to use NSObject

Comment: Why don't you want to use `NSObject`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. All of the collections in Foundation can store only Objective-C objects. Since a `struct` is not an Objective-C object, it cannot be stored in there.

But you could wrap your `struct` into a simple `NSObject` subclass and store that in the array.

Or with `NSValue`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

struct TestStruct {
    int a;
    float b;
};

...

NSMutableArray *theArray = [NSMutableArray new];    

...

struct TestStruct *testStructIn = malloc(sizeof(struct TestStruct));
testStructIn->a = 10;
testStructIn->b = 3.14159;

NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:testStructIn objCType:@encode(struct TestStruct)];
[theArray addObject:value];

free(testStructIn);

...

struct TestStruct testStructOut;
NSValue *value = [theArray objectAtIndex:0];
[value getValue:&testStructOut];

NSLog(@"a = %i, b = %.5f", testStructOut.a, testStructOut.b);
```

No real reason why one struct is heap allocated and one stack allocated, by the way. Just thought I'd do that to show it working.

Comment: @OneManCrew is correct. You can just wrap it in an NSValue.

Comment: Yeh you could use `NSValue`.