# Can a dispatch_queue_t be added to a NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to add a `dispatch_queue_t` to a `NSMutableArray` like so:

```
    NSMutableArray* queuesWaitingForTargetQueue = (__bridge NSMutableArray*)dispatch_queue_get_specific(targetQueue, WAITING_QUEUE_LIST_KEY);

    NSLog(@"    dispatch_get_current_queue() = %#x", (unsigned int)dispatch_get_current_queue());
    NSLog(@"    dispatch_get_main_queue()    = %#x", (unsigned int)dispatch_get_main_queue());
    NSLog(@"    currQueueId                  = %#x", (unsigned int)currQueueId);
    NSLog(@"    queuesWaitingForTargetQueue  = %#x (%@)", (unsigned int)queuesWaitingForTargetQueue, NSStringFromClass([queuesWaitingForTargetQueue class]));

    [queuesWaitingForTargetQueue addObject:(__bridge id)currQueueId];
```

The last line sometimes fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc08314eb)
```

While the output was:

```
 dispatch_get_current_queue() = 0x2879640
 dispatch_get_main_queue()    = 0x2879640
 currQueueId                  = 0x2879640
 queuesWaitingForTargetQueue  = 0x8672ae0 (__NSArrayM)
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to put a c-struct in an NSArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516991/whats-the-best-way-to-put-a-c-struct-in-an-nsarray). `dispatch_queue_t` is just a C struct.

Comment: BTW - use `%p` (without the casts) to log pointers.

Comment: @rmaddy: `dispatch_queue_t` is actually an Objective-C object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you for the hint. The linked solution solved my problem for iOS 5. I've now noticed that the code worked in iOS 7 already before.

Comment: and the %p is nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Your memory management is going to be a real problem here - your crash is almost for sure a pointer to a previously released object. If you really need to move the array around, then move it back and forth using the high level bridge casts (CFBridging...) from an id to a CFType (like a CFMutableDictionary), then use the CF object as the key. When done, CFRelease the CF object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no.

If you look up the return type of the various methods you're using, like dispatch_get_current_queue(), they return a value of type dispatch_queue_t. If you look up dispatch_queue_t, the docs say:

> dispatch_queue_t A dispatch queue is a lightweight object to which
>   your application submits blocks for subsequent execution.
>
> typedef struct dispatch_queue_s *dispatch_queue_t;

It's a struct. Structs are not objects. NSArrays can only hold objects.

Comment: `dispatch_queue_t` is actually an Objective-C object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues: *"Starting in the iOS 6.0 SDK and the Mac OS X 10.8 SDK, every dispatch object (including a dispatch_queue_t) is also an Objective-C object."*

Comment: I think this answer together with Martin's comment is the best explanation for me. I've noticed that my code works in iOS 7 Simulator, but not in iOS 5.1 Simulator. Thanks to both of you! I will adjust my code so it works in both versions.