# why can't we store C struct directly in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, c

I ran into an error when I was trying to store a C struct into a NSArray (I was able to solve it by converting into NSData as specified in the link below).  However, I am curious to understand why it did not work without all this hassle of using NSData.  [link to solution I used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516991/whats-the-best-way-to-put-a-c-struct-in-an-nsarray/)

Please note:  I don't want a solution, it is already solved.  I am just trying to improve my understanding of the fundamentals of Objective-C by understanding why the direct approach below did not work.

What I was trying to do: A simple program that allows a person to add a grocery item and mark it as done after adding to shopping cart

1. Define C struct with 3 elements (name of item, count and BOOL to keep track of whether it has been added to cart or not)
2. Each time a new item is created I do the following
   groceryItem *secondGroceryItem = malloc(sizeof(groceryItem)) ;
   secondGroceryItem->itemName="Beer" ;
   secondGroceryItem->count = 3 ;
   secondGroceryItem->purchased=NO ;
3. Then I add it to a NSMutableArray keeping track of grocery items using
   [myGroceryList addObject:(__bridge id)(secondGroceryItem)]

where myGroceryList is defined earlier as
    NSMutableArray *myGroceryList = [NSMutableArray array]  ;

This does not work.  I had to convert into a NSData before storing in NSMutableArray.  Why can't I just store a pointer to my C struct directly in the NSMutableArray?

Comment: A C struct is not an NSObject.  Only NSObject *pointers* can be stored in NSArrays.  You can (under some circumstances) use an NSValue as the "container" for your C struct.  Probably better than some NSData kluge, but still kinda flaky.  (And there are hardly ever cases where you'd need to use C structs unless you're doing some really weird stuff.)

Comment: I'm not sure this question is really answerable. The simple answer is, as Hot Licks said "because `NSArray` can only store objects". The more complicated answer means going back to the decisions that NeXT engineers made 20+ years ago. At any rate, the recommended solution is to convert your structure into a simple data class, making the fields into properties.

Comment: We also can't put ints, floats, chars, etc., in an `NSArray`.  An `NSArray` is a special type of array of Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be noted that the reason we can't put C-structs into `NSArray` isn't because of anything special about structs.  Instead, we should consider `NSArray` to be a special type of array.

We *can* put structs in arrays in Objective-C.  We know this because C programmers put structs in arrays.

`NSArray` (and `NSMutableArray` and all the other `NS` collection objects) is a special class designed to implement the array data structure specifically for Objective-C objects.  The fact that `NSArray` only allows Objective-C objects allows `NSArray` to do things like `makeObjectsPerformSelector:`.  We're sending an Objective-C message to everything in the array.  We couldn't allow this if we allowed non-Objective-C-objects into the array.

It's not just `structs` that aren't allowed into `NSArray`.  All the primitive data types are not allowed in an `NSArray`.  This even includes `NSInteger` and `CGFloat`, because remember, these are typedef'd primitives--not objects.

It should be noted however, that `NSArray` is not the only array-like data structure available to us in Objective-C.  Remember, Objective-C is a strict superset of C.  And as I already mentioned, C programmers are already putting structs into an array.

We can always use a C-style array.  In fact, although it's very rarely done (because of the power of Objective-C arrays), we can even create a C-style array of Objective-C objects.

Consider:

```
NSString *stringArray[3];
stringArray[0] = @"foo";
stringArray[1] = @"bar";
stringArray[2] = @"baz";

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    NSLog(@"%@", stringArray[i]);
}
```

This compiles, runs, and does exactly what you'd expect in Objective-C.  As such, we can do exact same with a `struct`:

```
typedef struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
} Foo;

Foo fooArray[3];
fooArray[0] = (Foo){.x = 1, .y = 2};
fooArray[1] = (Foo){.x = 3, .y = 4};
fooArray[2] = (Foo){.x = 5, .y = 6};

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    NSLog(@"Foo(x: %i, y: %i)", fooArray[i].x, fooArray[i].y);
}
```

Again, this is perfectly valid **Objective-C** code.

The question you have to ask yourself: Is it better to have a struct and deal with a C-style array, or would my struct be better as an object that I can put in an `NSArray`?  I wouldn't use a `struct` that I'm converting to `NSData` and back just for the sake of putting it into an `NSArray`...that seems like a mess.

Answer (score 3):

An NSArray or NSMutableArray consists of objects. C datatypes are not objects. So you can not store them directly in a NSArray.

I assume that you know how to create an object. Include in this object the variables with the C-datatype.

Once you have that, add that object to the NSArray:

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

YourObject *object1 = [[YourObject alloc] init];
[yourArray addObject: object1];
```

Comment: Thanks, it just seems an overkill to create a class for every small thing.  I guess I'll have to compare this against the overhead of having to go through NSData kludge or decide if I will need any of the special things NSArray gives me (i.e use a regular array instead) on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: This does also apply to NSDATA.