# Why won't my CGPoint save in a NSMutable array correctly?

Tags: iphone, uiview, cgpoint

So, I've based my code off of the answer found at:  [How can I add CGPoint objects to an NSArray the easy way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899600/how-can-i-add-cgpoint-objects-to-an-nsarray-the-easy-way)

My code now reads like:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    locationOne = [touch locationInView: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    NSLog(@"In touchesBegan");
    NSLog(@"x is: %.3f.  y is: %.3f", locationOne.x, locationOne.y);
    [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:locationOne]];
    NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:[points count]];
    CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];
    NSLog(@"in points array:  x is: %.3f, y is: %.3f", p.x ,p.y);
}

2011-06-16 13:21:57.367 canvas_test[7889:307] In touchesBegan
2011-06-16 13:21:57.371 canvas_test[7889:307] x is: 115.000.  y is: 315.500
2011-06-16 13:21:57.374 canvas_test[7889:307] in points array:  x is: 0.000, y is: 0.000
2011-06-16 13:22:00.982 canvas_test[7889:307] In touchesBegan
2011-06-16 13:22:00.985 canvas_test[7889:307] x is: 274.500.  y is: 386.000
2011-06-16 13:22:00.988 canvas_test[7889:307] in points array:  x is: 0.000, y is: 0.190
2011-06-16 13:22:11.476 canvas_test[7889:307] In touchesBegan
2011-06-16 13:22:11.480 canvas_test[7889:307] x is: 105.500.  y is: 140.500
2011-06-16 13:22:11.483 canvas_test[7889:307] in points array:  x is: 0.000, y is: 0.190
```

Does anybody have any idea what could possibly be going wrong?

edit:

I've noticed that anytime I check my points count, it's always at 0.  Is there a way of checking whether I initialized my NSMutableArray correctly?  I use 
points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
in the init function, and have NSMutableArray *points; in my .h file.  Do I need to do anything more to initiate the NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised this doesn't crash. You're reading beyond the end of the array:

```
NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:[points count]];
```

This should be:

```
NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:[points count] - 1];
```

or

```
NSValue *val = [points lastObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

`[points objectAtIndex:[points count]]` will always be out of range. The last object in the array will be at index `[points count] - 1`.

Alternatively you could just use `NSValue *val = [points lastObject]`.