# array of caLayer in iphone

Tags: iphone, calayer

i want to take the array of CALAYER:-

```
CALayer *layer3 = [CALayer layer];
    [layer3 setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)];
    [layer3 setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [layer3 setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [layer3 setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];

    // Center the layer in the view.
    [layer3 setPosition:CGPointMake(x,y)];
[[self.Image layer3] addSublayer:layer3];
```

By the above way i had made one point in the image.
But i want to draw the 10 point in the image.
I want to take the arrary of CALAyer.
Please help me .How can i take the array of CALAYER.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you have to store points in array and you can use that number of points whenever its required.

Comment: For how to store CGPoints in array, you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899600/how-can-i-add-cgpoint-objects-to-an-nsarray-the-easy-way

Answer (score -1):

```
    NSMutableArray *Arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CALayer *layer1 = [CALayer layer];
        [layer1 setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)];
        [layer1 setCornerRadius:5.0f];
        [layer1 setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [layer1 setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
         [Arr addObject:layer1];
    CALayer *layer3 = [CALayer layer];
        [layer3 setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)];
        [layer3 setCornerRadius:5.0f];
        [layer3 setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [layer3 setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
        [Arr addObject:layer3];
    CALayer *layer4 = [CALayer layer];
        [layer4 setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)];
        [layer4 setCornerRadius:5.0f];
        [layer4 setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [layer4 setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
        // [Arr addObject:layer4]; Center the layer in the view.
```

now take Individual Layer From Array...
   I Hope It Will Help To You Try Once

Comment: you can not add `CALayer` to `NSArray` as it is not confirming to `NSCopying` protocol.