# Drawing Histogram needs more accuracy in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, histogram

I am working in an app in which I need to draw Histogram of any inputed image. I can draw Histogram successfully but its not so sharp as its in PREVIEW in Mac OS.

As code is too large ,I have uploaded it to GitHub [Click here to Download](https://github.com/HarshitDaftary/Generate-Histogram-Graph-For-an-Image-in-iPhone)

The RGB Values are read in

```
  -(void)readImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    for (int yy=0;yy<height; yy++)
    {
        for (int xx=0; xx<width; xx++)
        {
            // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
            int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;
            for (int ii = 0 ; ii < 1 ; ++ii)
            {
                CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) ;
                CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) ;
                CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) ;
                // CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
                byteIndex += 4;

                // TYPE CASTING ABOVE FLOAT VALUES TO THAT THEY CAN BE MATCHED WITH ARRAY'S INDEX.

                int redValue = (int)red;
                int greenValue = (int)green;
                int blueValue = (int)blue;


                // THESE COUNTERS COUNT " TOTAL NUMBER OF PIXELS " FOR THAT  Red , Green or Blue Value IN ENTIRE IMAGE.

                fltR[redValue]++;
                fltG[greenValue]++;
                fltB[blueValue]++;                
            }
        }
    }
    [self makeArrays];
    free(rawData);
}
```

I stored values in c array variables , fltR,fltG,fltB.

I have a class ClsDrawPoint it has members

```
@property CGFloat x;
@property CGFloat y;
```

Then prepared an array containing objects of ClsDrawPoint having fltR[]'s index as X value and value for that index as Y value .

array is prepared and graph is drawn in

```
-(void)makeArrays
```

method

You may see the result

[image]

**Currently its not so accurate as it is in PREVIEW in mac for the same image. You can open an image in PREVIEW app in Mac and in Tools>AdjustColor , you will be able to see the Histogram of that image.
I think if my graph is accrate , it will be sharper. Kindly check my code and suggest me if you find anyway to make it more accurate.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pulled your sample down from Github and found that your `drawRect:` method in `ClsDraw` is drawing lines that are one pixel wide. Strokes are centered on the line, and with a width of 1, the stroke is split into half-pixels which introduces anti-aliasing.

I moved your horizontal  offsets by a half-pixel and rendering looks sharp. I didn't mess with vertical offsets, but to make them sharp you would need to round them and then move them to a half-pixel offset as well. I only made the following change:

```
#define OFFSET_X 0.5

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  if ([arrPoints count] > 0)
  {
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, graphColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 0.8);
    ClsDrawPoint *objPoint;
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < [arrPoints count] ; i++)
    {
      objPoint = [arrPoints objectAtIndex:i];
      CGPoint adjustedPoint = CGPointMake(objPoint.x+OFFSET_X, objPoint.y);
      CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, adjustedPoint.x, 0);
      CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
      CGContextSetLineJoin(ctx, kCGLineJoinRound);
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, adjustedPoint.x, adjustedPoint.y);
      CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, adjustedPoint.x, adjustedPoint.y);
      CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the new `OFFSET_X` and the introduction of `adjustedPoint`.

You might also consider using a `CGPoint` stuffed into an `NSValue` instance for your points instead of your custom class `ClsDrawPoint`, unless you plan to add some additional behavior or properties. More details available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899600/how-can-i-add-cgpoint-objects-to-an-nsarray-the-easy-way).

Comment: thanks for NSValue , I really didn't know this. Graph is accurate but still not so accurate as it is in preview.. Can you suggest me more ???

Comment: i tried hard but couldn't get any more way.... thanks . these up votes are for your handwork...